# shoulda-matchers attribute does not seem to be an attribute on model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, shoulda

I've just upgraded to shoulda-matchers 3.1.2 from 2.8.0 on Rails 4.1 and now my validate uniqueness scoped to test fails with this message;

```
  1) Invoice should validate that :invoice_no is case-sensitively unique within the scope of :ledger_id
     Failure/Error: it { is_expected.to validate_uniqueness_of(:invoice_no).scoped_to(:ledger_id)}

       Invoice did not properly validate that :invoice_no is case-sensitively
       unique within the scope of :ledger_id.
         :ledger_id does not seem to be an attribute on Invoice.
     # ./spec/models/invoice_spec.rb:6:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Here is my test

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe Invoice, :type => :model do
  it { is_expected.to validate_uniqueness_of(:invoice_no).scoped_to(:ledger_id)}
  it { is_expected.to validate_presence_of(:ledger_id)}
```

The test for the presence of :ledger_id passes.

Here is my model

```
  validates :ledger_id, presence: true
  validates_uniqueness_of :invoice_no, scope: :ledger_id, case_sensitive: false
```

Solution (I'm using machinist still)

```
  subject { Invoice.make!(ledger: Ledger.make!) }
  it { is_expected.to validate_uniqueness_of(:invoice_no).case_insensitive.scoped_to(:ledger_id)}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is your issue [thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers/issues/535)

Try this:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe Invoice, :type => :model do
 is_expected = expect(create(:invoice))
 it { is_expected.to 
 validate_uniqueness_of(:invoice_no).case_insensitive.scoped_to(:ledger_id)}
 it { is_expected.to validate_presence_of(:ledger_id)}
```